# How Do IModify Report Criteria?

Tags: civireport

I am trying to customize a report (Contribute/Summary) to compute LAST YEAR "to date" totals (so I can compare them with how we are doing so far this year).  I have created the new template/php files but am at a loss where to "subtract the one year" from the "current year-to-date field" before the query is done.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to first check out the [Advanced Fundraising Reports](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/net.ourpowerbase.reports.advancedfundraising) extension before you go too far down that road - I think it has the option you want.

Second - I've been working on [user-configurable date filters](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16195) - I'm hoping to get them into the next version of Civi, so you don't have to modify code to get a new filter.

Third - since you need this now and not later - you'll want to override one or both of these core files: 
CRM/Core/Form/Date.php 
CRM/Utils/Date.php (function relativeToAbsolute).